# C# Do we have Performance Issue in having private variable instead of having them as method arguments

Tags: c#, oop

==>  In my class methods, I am uisng `LINQ` query(and other processing statements) to derive a value which I store it in a private field of the class say `private int vendorId;`.

==> This private variable `vendorId` I refer it in other methods of that class.

**My Query**
Does this pose any performance issue?

Instead of declaring class level private variable should I instead pass those variable as method arguments?

```
public class VendorHandler
{
   private vendorId;
   List<obj> vendorList;
   int businessId;
   ...

    public method GetVendorStandard()
    {
         ....
         this.vendorId= ....;
         ...
         MakePayment();
    }

    private void MakePayment()
    {
        string vendorCode = this.vendorId + ....;
        List<obj> list = this.vendorList;
        ...
    }
```

Or should it be that, vendorId (and other method parameters) should be passed to MakePayment method like

```
private void MakePayment(int vendorId, List<obj> vendorList, int businessId)
```

Do we have  any performance issues if we declare them as private variables in class?

Comment: It depends, but it's often not good design. You add state to your handlers/services/managers/whatever where it isn't required. Often you would combine all data that needs to be passed around in a new class (and object thereof), e.g. a viewmodel, DTO, etc.

Comment: Any difference in performance will be in the nanoseconds anyway. Don't even think about performance here. Instead, formulate your classes and methods to reflect your business logic adequately.

Comment: It's a single extra pointer deref, I wouldn't even think about it. If you were designing a major class library to be used in tight loops of performance sensitive code, maybe, otherwise forget it

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is . . . ***No***.

The only real differences are

- Each instance of your class is carrying around 3 new fields, so a little extra memory.
- Your methods are now a little more difficult to test.

The real question, though, is a design question:

> Are these values actual attributes of each such entity (object) instance, or not?

If they are, then they should be properties of the class. If they aren't, then they should be passed as parameters.